# Angularjs: models binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I have directive which dynamically creates input tags. I need to get values of created inputs on change event. Instead of it the `name` attribute on `$scope` argument in the `controller` is undefined. How to get `ng-model` value in the directive controller?

```
module.directive('createControl', function($compile, $timeout){
   return {           
     transclude: true,
     restrict: 'A',   
     scope: {         
       name: '=name'
     },
     link: function(scope, element, attrs){
         // simplified version
         tag = '<input type="text" ng-model="name"/>'
         element.append(html);
     controller: function($scope){
         // In the controller I need to get value of created input on change event
         console.log($scope);
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: could you share complete code with directive declaration in html .pls set up a plunker code or jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you want to do, but I'm guessing it's something like this:

```js
module.directive('createControl', function($compile, $timeout){
   return {   
     transclude: true,
     restrict: 'A',   
     scope: {         
       name: '=name'
     },
     link: function(scope, element, attrs){
         // simplified version
         var tag = angular.element('<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-change="changed(name)">');
         element.append(tag);
         $compile(tag)(scope);
     },
     controller: function($scope){
         // In the controller I need to get value of created input on change event
         $scope.changed=function(name){
           console.log('changed to: '+name);
         }
     }
   }
});
```

The link function creates a new input element, compiles it with the `$compile` service and then links the new input element with `scope`. This works with the following markup:

```html
Hello {{myInput}}!
<div create-control name="myInput">  
</div>
```

Check out this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7XY90LXNn6gqpP47JaCH?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `controller` executed earlier than `directive`. So in controller should be `$watch`ed `$scope`, not html tags added in a `directive`. However I think a `controller` binded to a `directive` should not know about `directive` state, correct me if I am wrong.

So there is two approaches:

```
module.directive('createControl', function($compile, $timeout){
   return {   
     transclude: true,
     restrict: 'A',   
     scope: {         
        name: '=name'
     },
     link: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
         // simplified version
         var tag = angular.element('<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-change="changed(name)">');
         $element.append(tag);
         $compile(tag)(scope);
     },
     controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
         $scope.$watch('Name', function(){            
             console.log(arguments);                    
         });                                          
     }         
});
```

The second one:

```
module.directive('createControl', function($compile, $timeout){
   return {   
     transclude: true,
     restrict: 'A',   
     scope: {         
        name: '=name'
     },
     link: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
         // simplified version
         var tag = angular.element('<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-change="changed(name)">');
         $element.append(tag);
         $compile(tag)(scope);
         $element.find('input').on('change', function(){
             console.log($scope);
         })
     }
});
```